# weighted? proportion (e.g. 1/1 < 10/10)

Tags: classification, descriptive-statistics, feature-engineering

I was wondering if there was a way to express a proportion but weighting the numerator/denominator size. For example:

Say I have a categorical variable `X` with 3 possible values: `A, B, C` and I'm trying to predict effect `y` (either `1 or 0`)

I have 1 case of `X = A` and `y` is positive => 1/1

I have 10 cases of `X = B` and `y` is positive on five => 5/10

I have 25 cases of `X = C` and `y` is positive on all => 25/25

Then:

- if I process the feature as "number of positives per category", values **A and B would be equivalent**.
- if I process the feature as a proportion (positives/all), **A and C would be equivalent**.

None of those is desirable. Is there another way to better encode these?

Thanks!

(Note: the example is illustrative, I need it to generalize to multiple categories)

Comment: Your question is not clear, and example even less so. Could you reformulate it? In particular, how does "I have 1 case of `X = A` and `y` is positive" imply 1/1? What does 1/1 mean here?

Comment: in that case would be 1 example with feature `X = A` and that case is positive (`y = 1`)

Comment: Why then "I have 10 cases of X = B and y is positive on five" implies 1/10? Shouldn't it be 0/5? (0 examples with feature `X = A` and 5 cases positive)?

Comment: @psarka you're right, I corrected it. It's 5/10

Comment: @PabloFernandez This still doesn't make sense to me. If you want an unconditional (you don't know X) prediction of $Y$, you would just use the crude proportion of Y (1 + 5 + 25) / (1 + 10 + 25).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the formula for the posterior mean of a Bernoulli distribution with a beta prior. This is simply $\frac{s + α}{n + α + β}$ where $s$ is the number of succeses, $n$ is the number of trials, and $α$ and $β$ are adjustable prior parameters. For example, if you choose $α = β = 1$, then

```
 s    n    output
 1    1     .67
 5   10     .50
25   25     .96
```

Comment: (+1) I've heard of the special case of setting $\alpha = \beta = 1$ as the "+1" estimator, because it's as simple as just adding 1 "success" and 1 failure to your estimate. It surprising how many real world application issues are fixed using this. Also, since the OP asked for a method that generalizes to multiple categories, this is as easy as adding one outcome to each category in the multinomial case.